# Как передвинуть окно в GLUT?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

Задача: Открыть окно, перевести его в полноэкранный режим, а затем вернуть в обратное состояние. Проблема состоит в том, что после возврата из полноэкранного режима "рамка" пропадает и окно оказывается "приклеенным" к левому верхнему углу.
Как можно переместить окно чуть левее?
Вот код:

```
void changeSize(int w, int h) {
    // определяем окно просмотра
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    // используем матрицу проекции
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    // Reset матрицы
    glLoadIdentity();
    /*glOrtho(0.0f, 400.0f, 400.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);*/
    glOrtho(0.0f, w, h, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    // вернуться к модели
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void renderScene(void) {
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f(0.0, 400.0);
    glVertex2f(200.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(200.0, 400.0);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void processNormalKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
        if (key == 27)
            exit(0);
        else if (key == 'f')
        {
            int mod = glutGetModifiers();
            if (mod == GLUT_ACTIVE_ALT) {
                glutReshapeWindow(1280, 700);

            }
            else
                glutFullScreen();
        }
    }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // инициализация
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(43, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(1280, 700);
    glutCreateWindow("Урок 2");
    // регистрация
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);

    // Новая функция изменения размеров окна
    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);

    glutKeyboardFunc(processNormalKeys);
    // основной цикл
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `glutPositionWindow(100,1000);` Не работает?

Comment: Работает! О такой функции не знал, спасибо

Comment: OpenGL совершенно никак не отвечает за окна. В вашем случае этим занимается glut